# C#/Windows Phone escape characters in AppResources

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, localization, windows-phone-8

If I use `AppResources.myText` in my code to set texts of textblocks, all the escape characters get converted and my localized text becomes useless.
e.g. `Hello\nWorld!` becomes `Hello\\nWorld!`

As a result the textblock shows this:

```
Hello\\nWorld!
```

Instead of:

```
Hello
World!
```

Which escape characters should I use in my AppResources for localized strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work the same as [doing this in other resource files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931114/carriage-return-line-feed-in-net-resource-file-app-globalresources).

> Lets say you want to type in hello world
>
> Type hello followed by shift+enter and world.