# New line is not working in MessageBox in C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

Short question: I have a string in my resources: "This is my test string {0}\n\nTest"

I'm trying to display this string in my Messagebox:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format(Properties.Resources.About, 
    Constants.VERSION), 
    Properties.Resources.About_Title, MessageBoxButton.OK, 
    MessageBoxImage.Information);
```

However I don't get new lines. The \n still show up as characters, not as new lines.

I also tried to use a workaround like mystring.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine) but this also doesn't change anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Funny thing to mention: Replace("\n", "somethingelse") doesn't change anything.

Edit2: Shift+Enter in my Resource-File instead of \n seems to work... Strange behaviour anyway

Comment: Unfortunately not. It shows \r\n in plaintext

Comment: This is interesting ..when I use OP's string by assigning to a variable it works..But when I place it in the Resources it doesn't work.

Comment: Is your resource file is in ResX format? did you use VS resx editor to add resource string?

Comment: Environment.NewLine will give "\r\n" when run on Windows. If you are generating strings for Unix based environments, you don't want the "\r"

Comment: when the string is read from string table '\r\n' becoming '\\r\\n' thats why shift+enter working not \r\n

Comment: In regards to the `Replace("\n", "somethingelse") doesn't change anything` comment, that is because you should be looking for `\\n` instead of just `\n`.  What you think is a new line reference is more than likely being escaped by the time you try to replace it.  If you have a situation where you pull text from a DB and spit it out to a MessageBox then try to use `MessageBox.Show(_settings.ContactInfo.Replace("\\n","\n"));`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Put a place holder where you want to put new line and in the code where you use that resource string, just replace it with new line: string resource: "This is first line.{0}This is second line.{0}This is third line." You will use this resource string like this: MessageBox.Show(string.Format(MyStringResourceClass.MyStringPropertyName, Environment.NewLine));

OR

Unconventional Method
    But i just now got it working by coping newline from word directly (or anyother place) & pasting it inside the resource string file.

```
It was simple..
OR
```

\r\n characters will be converted to new line when you display it by using message box or assign it to text box or whenever you use it in interface.

In C# (like most C derived languages), escape characters are used to denote special characters such as return and tab, and + is used in place of & for string concatenation.

To make your code work under C# you’ve got two options... the first is to simply replace the NewLine with the return escape character \n ala:

```
MessageBox.Show("this is first line" + "\n" + "this is second line");
```

The other method, and more correct is to replace it instead with Environment.NewLine which theoretically could change depending on the system you are using (however unlikely).

```
MessageBox.Show("this is first line" + Environment.NewLine + "this is second line");
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all? OP already using \n but asking why it is output as-is rather than being shown a line-break.

Comment: In your case MessageBox.Show("This is my test string {0}"+"\n"+"\n"+"Test");

Comment: but how can I do this within my resources? I'd like to save my whole string in resources

Comment: I think between `"Environment.NewLine"` should not be quotes.

Comment: the problem is that I can't split my string. I just want to load the string from my resources with linebreaks.

Comment: \r\n characters will be converted to new line when you display it by using message box or assign it to text box or whenever you use it in interface.

Comment: `Environment.Newline` should be outside the quotes, now you're just concatenating "Environment.NewLine" to the rest.

Comment: Put a place holder where you want to put new line and in the code where you use that resource string, just replace it with new line:

string resource: "This is first line.{0}This is second line.{0}This is third line."

You will use this resource string like this:
MessageBox.Show(string.Format(MyStringResourceClass.MyStringPropertyName, Environment.NewLine));

Answer (score 7):

In the resource editor seperate your string content by using shift+enter. Or else, edit your ResX file in xml editor and using enter key create a new line for your resource string.

Refer this link for detail info: [Carriage Return/Line in ResX file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931114/carriage-return-line-feed-in-net-resource-file-app-globalresources)

Comment: indeed shift+enter is the easiest way !

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
    String outputMessage = string.Format("Line 1{0}Line 2{0}Line 3", Environment.NewLine);
    MessageBox.Show(outputMessage);
```

A further example with another variable:

```
    String anotherValue = "Line 4";
    String outputMessage = string.Format("Line 1{0}Line 2{0}Line 3{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, anotherValue);
    MessageBox.Show(outputMessage);
```

Comment: add `MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel` then it will not break lines...

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution : in the resource designer : use ctrl+Enter to insert a new line in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

removing the MessageBoxButtons.OK and MessageBoxImage. Information.

```
 MessageBox.Show(String.Format(Properties.Resources.About, 
Constants.VERSION), 
Properties.Resources.About_Title);
```