# <br/> tag in Resource File to provide break space not working on Click over Save button

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, xhtml

I have used `<br/>` tag in Resource File to provide break space. First time the Message from Resource files reflect correctly
but when I click on Save button then on same page the `<br/>` tag do not break the line and it reflects in Message content.
Can please anyone suggest the solution.

I also tried `<br>` tag but the same results.

Comment: Ref this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931114/carriage-return-line-feed-in-net-resource-file-app-globalresources

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try to put the content in Raw if it is Razor like `@Html.Raw(ResourceContent)`.Sometime it can help !

Comment: I am using User Control. so what is the alternative for <%: Html.DisplayFor   %>