# How to write new line character \n in resx file?

Tags: c#, .net, resx

ow to write new line character \n in resx file (e.g MyFile.resx)?

Example: I have resx file with property `MyMessage = "One line\nNextLine"`

When I used:
`MessageBox.Show(MyFile.MyMessage)` I had a message in one line (without Enter).

Shift + Enter in the resource editor doesn`t work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Carriage Return/Line Feed in .Net Resource File (App\_GlobalResources)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931114/carriage-return-line-feed-in-net-resource-file-app-globalresources)

Comment: You can also try to use \r\n

Comment: I have just tried Shift + enter works

Comment: none of this work.

Comment: I really tried everything, even all propositions from a similar question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you open the .resx file with the *Managed Resources Editor* you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter multi line messages:

[image: Multiline text in resource editor]

If you open the .resx file with a text editor the corresponding entry looks like this:

```
  <data name="MultiLineMessage" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Test
Message</value>
  </data>
```

[image]

And calling it with

```
MessageBox.Show(Properties.Resources.MultiLineMessage);
```

return this box:

[image: Messagebox with multiline message]

So, everything seems to work as expected. So please re-check if you really have a multi line message in your resource file.